# Salesforce Flow - Email Reminders and Pausing

Tags: flow-builder, salesforce-flow

I have searched the internet for days to find a solution, but cannot.

The use case for this flow is for "technical assistance" cases. We currently have a case status field that displays whether a case is New, In Progress, Pending Closed, etc.

When a user manually sets the case status field to "Pending Close", we want the following to occur:

1. Send an email to the requestor, notifying them that their case is
   going to close
2. Wait 3 days - within this time frame if a response is received, set status to "In Progress" and end flow, if no response is
   received, move to step 3.
3. Send an email reminder to the requestor
4. Wait 2 days - within this time frame if a response is received, set status to "In Progress" and end flow, if no response is
   received, move to step 5.
5. Send a closure email to the requestor and set status to "Closed"
6. End.

Logically, a Record-Triggered Flow (execute on Case Status field update to Pending Closed) with pauses makes sense. However, you cannot pause a Record-Triggered Flow.

I have also already tried a Record Triggered Flow that calls an autolaunched subflow, but realized that "You can't pause a flow interview whose associated flow is referenced by a Subflow element in a record-triggered flow."

Does anyone have any ideas on how else I could accomplish this, preferably via Flow?

Comment: for steps 3 and 5 - this would normally be done with a record-triggered flow with scheduled paths. steps 2 and 4 could be handled by flow on EmailMessage

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using by using **Scheduled Tasks to Your Flow**.

You can take a look here:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/record-triggered-flows/add-a-scheduled-task-to-your-flow

You can use custom fields to controll and check the entry conditions for running what path the flow will follow.

Regarding the email, you can use both: EmailMessage or an Email Alert.